# Remove Brackets on Disabled Field

Tags: javascript, xpages

This may be an easy one, but I'm looking for a way to remove the [ ] brackets from a disabled field. I've already tried `value = value.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");` but that hasn't worked. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong spot?

Comment: Is it a document data source field with multi value content? Try looking at the multivalue separator.

Comment: Is that multivalue field? Brackets are usually part of the toString() call over Vector, so @Implode/join can do it, too.

Comment: It is not multi value content. It's just a field generating a random/unique number. Here is my code for the field: `session.evaluate("@Unique")`

Comment: I used the separator to fix it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get square brackets just because you mark an edit box control (assuming that this is what you're using here) as "disabled". As Per and Frantisek already pointed out square brackets appear if an array of some type is displayed as plain string. Even if your data only consists of a single value it still could be an array.

Of course you're free to use some kind of cosmetics here but the preferred option would by to first check whether the rendered data indeed is an array (a.k.a. multivalue field content), next find out the separator used (maybe an colon) and then add this separator to the control's multipleSeparator property (All Properties >> basics >> multipleSeparator)

EDIT:
glad to see it works. But most probably it wasn't the dash in your unique value: the method you're using always returns an array (a java vector to be precise). So in that case the proper solution would be

```
session.evaluate("@Unique")[0]
```

The separator property is obsolete then

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that about the brackets. I'm using code to generate a random/unique number. The result is this: DTET-9FML48  So I'm assuming the - is the separator property you're talking about?

Comment: I was able to use the separator property to remove them. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe that the dash has been causing this; see my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to call replace with a lower case like this:

```
value.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J3GhE/)**